# Promise... Return type instead of Promise<Type>

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, promise, return-type

I'm trying to achieve something that seems impossible in typescript due to it's asynchronous nature.

I basically have a net.Socket object to communicate with a server through TCP protocole.

Here is what I would like to achieve :

```js
import * as net from 'net'

class TCPClient {
  // The member used to communicate with the server
  client: net.Socket;

[...]

  /** 
   * Method called in another portion of code.
   * In this method, I call client.write to send data to server.
   * As first param, I put the command. As second param, a callback that is called when the
   * data is sent.
   * I listen then to the 'data' event to read the response from the server.
   * I store the response into a variable. I return the variable.
   * PROBLEM: Due to the asyncronous type of NodeJS, the variable appears as empty.
   **/
  command(cmd: string): string{
    var res : string;
    
    this.client.write(cmd, () => {
      this.client.on('data', response => {
        res = response.toString();
      });
    });
    
    return res;
  }
[...]

}
```

Comment: you can't return an asynchronous result synchronously in ANY language (typescript does not have an asynchronous nature)

Answer (score 1):

You have to make an asynchroneous method using Promises, something like:

```
command(cmd: string): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.client.write(cmd, () => {
      this.client.on('data', response => {
        resolve(response.toString());
      });
    });
  })
}
```

But to make it simpler you may use async/await in your calling code.